# get return value as -1 from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to see if my stored procedure can return -1 some values based on a if condition, snipped stored proc is as follows.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [StateMachine].[UpdateSnapshots] 


(@SystemName [nvarchar](128)= 'test_system',
@IntrestingEvents VARCHAR(128)='test_event',
@StateMachine_JSON [nvarchar] (max) = 'test_json',
@StateMachine_Object [nvarchar] (max)='test_object',
@CrossbarRouter VARCHAR(128) = 'text_xbar1') AS

BEGIN

DECLARE

@SystemNameValue [nvarchar](128),
@CrossbarValue [nvarchar](128),
@IsCrossbarNotNull int,
@IsCrossbarNull int,
@CrossbarLock int

select @SystemNameValue=count(systemname) from [StateMachine].[Snapshots] with (nolock) where SystemName=@SystemName



IF @SystemNameValue=0
BEGIN 
INSERT INTO [StateMachine].[Snapshots] (SystemName, IntrestingEvents, StateMachine_JSON, StateMachine_Object, CrossbarRouter) VALUES (@SystemName, @IntrestingEvents, @StateMachine_JSON, @StateMachine_Object, @CrossbarRouter)
END

select @CrossbarValue = isnull(count(CrossbarRouter),0) from [StateMachine].[Snapshots] with (nolock) where (CrossbarRouter=@CrossbarRouter and SystemName = @SystemName) 
select @IsCrossbarNotNull = isnull(count(CrossbarRouter),0) from [StateMachine].[Snapshots] with (nolock) where CrossbarRouter is not null and SystemName = @SystemName
select @IsCrossbarNull = isnull(count(CrossbarRouter),0) from [StateMachine].[Snapshots] with (nolock) where CrossbarRouter is null and SystemName = @SystemName
select @CrossbarLock = isnull(count(CrossbarRouter),0) from [StateMachine].[Snapshots] with (nolock) where (CrossbarRouter != @CrossbarRouter and SystemName = @SystemName) 

IF @CrossbarLock = 1
    RETURN -1



IF (@CrossbarValue = 0 and @IsCrossbarNotNull = 0) OR @IsCrossbarNull = 0
BEGIN
UPDATE [StateMachine].[Snapshots] SET IntrestingEvents=@IntrestingEvents, StateMachine_JSON=@StateMachine_JSON, StateMachine_Object=@StateMachine_Object, CrossbarRouter = @CrossbarRouter WHERE SystemName=@SystemName;
END
IF @CrossbarValue = 1 
BEGIN
UPDATE [StateMachine].[Snapshots] SET IntrestingEvents=@IntrestingEvents, StateMachine_JSON=@StateMachine_JSON, StateMachine_Object=@StateMachine_Object WHERE SystemName=@SystemName and CrossbarRouter=@CrossbarRouter;
END
END

GO
GRANT EXECUTE ON [StateMachine].[UpdateSnapshots] TO sp_executor
```

If I am trying to do this I am getting following error,

> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest that it's likely that there is another issue with your Stored Procedure that is not directly related to the use of the `RETURN` statement. Perhaps it would be useful to see the remainder of the code?

Comment: Are you sure it is on that particular `RETURN` statement? Can you show the whole stored proc?

Comment: sure I can show you the whole stored proc.

Comment: thanks for the edits.

Comment: This code works for me, I can't seem to reproduce your error

Comment: You wrap all other `IF` statements with `BEGIN / END`, except that one... try wrapping and see if that works for you.

Comment: You might want to read this before you continue splattering NOLOCK hints everywhere. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Are you trying to run the code directly instead of as a stored proc?  You cannot use return with a value when just running it directly from SSMS.  It only works in the context of calling a stored procedure.

Comment: Why are there parentheses around the sproc parameters?  Are you trying to create a function instead?